# How can I extract the contents of a Python xar file?

Tags: python, xar

I have a `.xar` file. [.xar is an exectuable archive file format developed by Meta/Facebook for creating self-contained Python binaries.](https://github.com/facebookincubator/xar/blob/main/README.md) I would like to extract its contents into a directory so I can look around and see what's inside the archive. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For a .xar (or any other compression/archive format) I use the free program The Unarchiver: https://theunarchiver.com

If you're not running macOS: Their command line tools also work on Windows and Linux.